# How best to read the man pages?

Tags: manpage

When reading man pages, a lot of extra characters are shown on screen. Which of the following commands can help to deal with this problem?

1. `grep`
2. `pg`
3. `more`
4. `row`
5. `col`

I think it's `more` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try this: `LANG=C man some_command`, leave the rest untouched during this test.

Answer (score 1):

`more` is used for pagination. Say you need to read some long output by page and press enter to goto next content. If this is what is meant by your question then yes `more` is the option. [[`more` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/more)].

try `man grep` & `man grep | more` - you will know the difference.

`grep` is used for filtering. [[grep manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grep)]

Comment: Yes there is a difference and doing `man grep | more` is *worse*.  By default `man` will use `less`.  And `less` is more than `more`.

Comment: less is used by default anyway. I am not sure the OP would gain anything by piping to more.

Comment: @haziz if you use custom shell colors it does ;)